# How do you change/modify certain parts of multiple hrefs on keyup using jquery?

Tags: jquery, href, each, keyup

I have a single input with a value set.

I have 2/multiple a tags with 2 different hrefs set with the first set input value

If I change the input on keyup, I want to only change/modify only the previous set value and keep the rest of the href the same except the previous value. 
I have a fiddle of this, it is sort of working but not well, Im doing something wrong here. 
Any help or advice would be apreciated.
https://jsfiddle.net/nlstm/do6eL1z4/1/

```
<input id="MYinput" type="text" value="test"></input> 

<br><br>
<a id="w3s" href="https://www.example1.com?q=">Test1</a>
<br>
<a id="w3s" href="https://www.example2.com?q=">Test2</a>
<br><br>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


var OriginalValue = $("#MYinput").val(); 

$('a#w3s').each(function(){

    var allHrefs = $(this).attr("href");

    var FinalHrefs = allHrefs + OriginalValue;

    var CompleteHrefs = $(this).attr("href",FinalHrefs)


});





$('#MYinput').keyup(function(){  

var textFromInput = $("#MYinput").val();   

$('a#w3s').each(function(){


    var urlKey = $(this).prop("href").split(OriginalValue)[0];

    var FinalHref = urlKey + textFromInput;

    var CompleteFinal = $(this).attr("href",FinalHref)


});

});





</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your links from `id` to `class`. The id attribute must be unique in the whole document.

Also, `<input>` is a void element and therefore does not require a closing `</input>` tag.

Iterate through your links and store the original `href` value as a data item. Learn more about [`jQuery.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and how to store arbitrary data on elements.

Create a function that iterates your links that retrieves the original href value stored previously, appends the input value and updates the current href. Note the [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).

Utilise this function by binding it to your `keyup` event listener and also invoke the function synchronously so that the existing input value is appended to already existing links.

```js
var links = $("a.link");

function appendInputValue () {
  links.each(function () {
    var currentValue = encodeURI($("input").val());
    var originalHref = $(this).data("originalHref");
    $(this).attr("href", originalHref + currentValue);
    console.log(originalHref + currentValue);
  });
}

links.each(function () {
  $(this).data("originalHref", $(this).attr("href"));
});

$("input").on("keyup", function () {
  appendInputValue();
});

appendInputValue();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="test">

<p><a class="link" href="https://www.example1.com?q=">Test1</a></p>
<p><a class="link" href="https://www.example2.com?q=">Test2</a></p>
```

Comment: Wow! Impressive. I think that works pretty well. I believe this is the right answer. Thank you very much.